# c# create class inside another class

Tags: c#, class, nested

Here is the code:

```
public class Alpha
{
   public Alpha()
   {
       Beta beta = new Beta();
   }
   public class Beta
   {
   }
}
```

I instantiate Alpha like this:

```
Alpha alpha = new Alpha();
```

Why can't I access beta from Alpha?
When I type "Alpha." visual studio won't show "beta" as a choice.
And also why can't I use "public" for alpha or beta?

Comment: its a local variable in the context of the constructor, what do you expect?

Comment: i though i knew what you wanted but i am confused again now

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you trying to access the local `beta` variable within `Alpha`s constructor or `Beta`, the class? You can access the class via `Alpha.Beta`. If you want to access an instance of that class which is contained within `Alpha`, you need to expose a public property of type `Beta`..

Comment: Thanks to everybody who answered. I had misunderstood some things... Now all is clear! The correct answer 'tick' goes to the first who answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable beta is only created locally in the constructor of your Alpha class and will go out of scope as soon as the constructor finishes, so you cannot access the beta variable from outside.
To reach the variable outside of class A, you have to define a member property in A with a public accessor, like:

```
public class Alpha
{
    // property to access member variable from outside
    public Beta beta{ get; private set; }

    public Alpha()
    {
         // initialize the member with a new instance
         beta = new Beta();
    }
    public class Beta
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Alpha.Beta ab = new Alpha.Beta();
```

Comment: incorrect, this just creates a new instance of Beta

Comment: True, but thats how I interpret it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Create a class called Alpha.cs
In this sample is created a metodo to access at beta property.

```
 public class Alpha
    {
        public Alpha()
        {
            betaTest = new Beta();
        }

        private Beta betaTest = null;

        public Beta BetaTest
        {
            get { return betaTest; }
            set { betaTest = value; }
        }



        public class Beta
        {
        }

    }
```

After that you can instantiate both Alpha, and Beta and use them as you see fit.

I attach a short example

```
Alpha alpha = new Alpha();
Alpha.Beta b = new Alpha.Beta();
b = alpha.BetaTest;
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need to add property to `Alpha` class see [this code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5qCvAC)